# portcommunicationserviced using too much CPU

Tags: 14.04, epson

Process usr/sbin/portcommunicationserviced is taking too much memory 229%

[image]

PS: Ubuntu 14.04 with i3wm window manager.

[image: mgur.com/7ASrA.png]

Comment: I have uploaded the clear image which is screenshot of running htop.

Comment: Which package does this file belong to? (run `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/portcommunicationserviced`) It does not seem to come with any official Ubuntu package, at least according to [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=portcommunicationserviced). It is also not part of *i3*. Can you please check if the problem persists when using other window managers? Also, do you have this problem immediately after booting/login or does it take some time?

Comment: epson-port-communication-service: /usr/sbin/portcommunicationserviced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me after installing an Epson driver. Solved removing it:

```
apt-get remove epson-port-communication-service
```